# Castle Windsor automatic property injection of non-public property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, property-injection

I've setup Castle Windsor in my ASP.NET Mvc 3 project and added the following property on `HomeController`:

```
    private IUserService UserService
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

When I try using `UserService` in an action method it's always null. But, if I change the property to `public` it gets automatically instantiated by Castle Windsor.

Is it possible to have automatic property injection with non-public properties?

Comment: If you can't set the property, why should Windsor be able to set it? Badly designed IMHO.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to check since I couldn't find any info on it.

Comment: It is possible to craft some hack to work around it... it's just not worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible for the reason that @Mauricio Scheffer comment outlines